# Problems connecting an Arduino Uno to a Commodore 64 Joystick port

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

I have made up a DB9 connector, which is the connector that fits the Commodore 64's joystick port. A small program on the Arduino sends HIGH signals to pins 1,2,3 and 4 of the connector. Another small program on the Commodore 64 reads the state of the joystick port (joystick port #1) and prints it out. However, the Commodore 64 is not registering the signal changes on the port pins. What am I doing wrong?

Is the problem due to the Arduino being unable to supply enough current, and if so, how do I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Almost impossible tell what the problem is without you telling us what it is that a Commodore 64 expects from its joystick. THe problem is not the Arduino supplying current because signals contain essentially no current.

Comment: Did you connect the Arduino ground to the joystick port ground?

Comment: You have asked the exact same question on retrocomputing.se, and the two communities do not share the clarifications and comments so it just takes twice the effort to reach an answer.

Comment: Here is Mario Gianota's similar question on Retrocomputing Stack Exchange: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18193

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can find, the atari control port and game pad are active low connections. A pin is left open for a high, and pulled to ground via a switch to register as a low or triggered. Your board needs to pull the line low with a relay or possibly a transistor or mosfet.

You may be able to pull it low via a digital pin, but you would need to ensure that at the very least your arduino board is tied to the same ground as the control port.

Answer (score 1):

An atari-style joystick (i.e. the C64 one) is simply made by 5 switches pulling to the ground the signal lines. The chip inside IIRC was a CIA, and were substantially just GPIOs.

So just tie the common to ground and enable pullups on your inputs, it will work.

If you need extra 'features' (like the turbo fire) you should give it 5V too (look on the net for the pinout, I don't remember)